# Nested for loop to look at every index in the array and prints it out

Tags: java

I'm very new to java and I am super confused on how I'd set up a nested for loop to look at every index of an array (nested since it will need to look at both the rows/columns) and then to copy the field into a copy and then return the copy. I've been told to firstly create a local array the same size as the field and then set up the nested for loop and copy the field into the copy and then return the copy. The "copying" stuff is very weird to me and confusing, but I need to return a copy because if it returns only the name of the array, it is actually returning the address in memory- so for security reasons I need return a copy and not the address. Any help would be most appreciated!

here's what the beginning of my code looks like:

```
public class Matrix
{
   //field for two dim arrays
   private int [][] matrixVals;

   //constructor
   public Matrix (int mVals[][])
   {
      //call the setMatrixVals( ) method to assign the correct information to the private field
      setMatrixVals(mVals);
   }

   //setter method
   public void setMatrixVals (int [][] mVals)
   {
      int rows = mVals.length;
      int cols = mVals[0].length;
      matrixVals = new int[rows][cols];
  
      //set up nested for loop
      //assign the elements of the mVals parameter to the coressonding elements of the matrixVals feild
      for(int i = 0; i < rows; i++)
      {
        for(int j = 0; j < cols; j++)
        {
           matrixVals[i][j] = mVals[i][j];
        }
      }
   }

   //getter method
   public int [][] getMatrixVals()
   {
      //create local array that is the same size as the field 
      int [][] mCopy = matrixVals;
  
      //set up nested for loop and copy the field into the copy and then retrun the copy
  
   }
```

Thank you so much in advance!

Comment: If you need to print the contents of the array, you can implement a method `print` in `Matrix` class.  If you _really_ need to copy the array in getter/setter/constructor, you should implement a single static helper/utility method and call it whenever needed.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to print the values why don't you simply do the following?

```java
public void getMatrixVals() {
  for(int i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
    for(int j = 0; j < cols; j++) {
       System.out.println(mVals[i][j]);
    }
  }  
}
```

I am having a hard time understanding the need for a copy of your original matrix.